# How to format c++ array initializer lists

Tags: c++, arrays, formatting, visual-studio-2017, initializer-list

I am having trouble getting Visual Studio to format my initializer lists correctly. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfcaq.png) is how it looks currently, and IMO it is very ugly.

I like doing it that way, and it looks [very clean in c#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQiZT.png).
I know I did it a little differently in c++ than in c#. :)

I am using Unreal Engine, hence the TArray type("Affixes" is also a TArray).

c++:

```
    Affixes.Append(TArray<FAffixGenerator>{
        FAffixGenerator(
            EStatsType::Local_IncreasedPhysicalDamage,
            EAffixType::Prefix,
            TArray<EEquipableType>
        {
            EEquipableType::Axe,
                EEquipableType::Sword
        },
            TArray<FAffixValues2D>
            {
                FAffixValues2D("Hefty", 0, FVector2D(10, 15)),
                    FAffixValues2D("Bulky", 5, FVector2D(16, 30)),
                    FAffixValues2D("Heavy", 10, FVector2D(31, 45)),
                    FAffixValues2D("Great", 15, FVector2D(46, 65)),
                    FAffixValues2D("Mighty", 20, FVector2D(66, 90)),
                    FAffixValues2D("Massive", 25, FVector2D(91, 120))
            })
    });
```

c#:

```
        Affixes.Add(new AffixGenerator()
        {
            StatType = EStatType.Local_IncreasedPhysicalDamage,
            AffixType = EAffixType.Prefix,
            ItemTypes = new List<EEquipableType>
            {
                EEquipableType.Axe,
                EEquipableType.Sword
            },
            GenerationValues = new List<AffixValues2D>
            {
                new AffixValues2D("Hefty", 0, new MinMaxValue(10, 15)),
                new AffixValues2D("Bulky", 5, new MinMaxValue(16, 30)),
                new AffixValues2D("Heavy", 10, new MinMaxValue(31, 45)),
                new AffixValues2D("Great", 15, new MinMaxValue(46, 65)),
                new AffixValues2D("Mighty",20, new MinMaxValue(66, 90)),
                new AffixValues2D("Massive", 25, new MinMaxValue(91, 120))
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should probably tag this for whatever version of Visual Studio you are using since the problem is with the IDE's auto formatting. Its not a code issue.

Comment: Please post code as code, not as images.

Comment: I think the reason for the image is the IDE messes up the user format. And the OP is trying to show this.

Comment: Oh, I thought it would be easier if I showed images, my bad. I'll make an edit.

Comment: @Wrekk How would it be easier in describing problem in images? If it can be represented as text - it should be text.

Comment: Because the formatting was bad for me, and it might not be for you. I made an edit with text.

Comment: @Wrekk "_Because the formatting was bad for me, and it might not be for you._" So, please explain, how does that forbid you, to format the code, that you show, in whatever manner VS formats it for you?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but whenever I copy paste the code(I need many affixes), it auto formats it. I could turn that off, but honestly, I was just looking for a way to make it format it correctly the first time around.